# Angular Change image src depending on class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If image has 'loaded' class, i need to change image src to "{{item.preview2}}"

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<img src="{{item.preview}}" class="grid-img" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so what is stopping you in doing that?

Answer (score 1):

```
directive('loaded', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope){
             scope.item.preview = scope.item.preview2
        }

    }

})
```

and in html

```
<img ng-src="{{item.preview}}" class="grid-img" />
```

Comment: i want to handle when image will get class="loaded"

Comment: than you need to add watcher, but it's not really angular way. You should not watch for class you should react on data changed. I think something is wrong with your task

Answer (score 1):

In the case you describe I would just use ng-if to control what elements are rendered to the DOM. for example:

```
<img ng-if="item.loaded" src={{item.preview2}} class="grid-img-loaded"/>
<img ng-if="!item.loaded" src={{item.preview}} class="grid-img"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need handle case, when image in ng-repeat will have class="loaded"

Comment: I am suggesting you use a property that is set when the item is loaded (item.loaded). From there you can control what goes in the DOM using standard angular directives.