# How to change img src in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

[Angular 2: Get reference to a directive used in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345618/angular-2-get-reference-to-a-directive-used-in-a-component/39406446?noredirect=1#comment66139881_39406446)

I want to change img src on hover.for reference go through this link:--

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37688325/4102561

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Change image src depending on class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319475/angular-change-image-src-depending-on-class)

Comment: the solution on this page offers an example of control via mouse events, not a class dependency

Answer (score 3):

You can use **mouseenter** and **mouseout** on ***host element*** as shown below,

Look at working demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/GfgZ46?p=preview

```
    //our root app component
import {Component, Directive, Output, EventEmitter, Input, SimpleChange} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  host: {
    '(mouseenter)':'MouseEnter()'
    '(mouseout)':'MouseOut()'
   },
  template: `
    <img [src]="source"/>
    `
})
export class App {
  source='images/angular.png';

  MouseEnter(){
    console.log('Hovering');
    this.source = 'images/car.png';  
  }

  MouseOut(){
    this.source='images/angular.png';
  }
}
```

Comment: my HTML:--<img class="badge_alignment" [src]="source"
       width="50px" height="50px"   on-mouseover='MouseEnter()' on-mouseout='MouseOut()' >      is that a correct way to change image source on hover?

Comment: what is on-mouseover and on-mouseout?

Comment: My Html;--<img _ngcontent-luk-5="" class="badge_alignment" height="50px" width="50px" src="assets/img/{{key}}_inactive.png">  Component.ts;--  public source='assets/img/{{key}}_inactive.png';
    
     MouseEnter(){
    console.log('Hovering');
    this.source = 'assets/img/{{key}}_active.png';  
  }
     MouseOut(){
         console.log('mouseout');
    this.source='assets/img/{{key}}_inactive.png';
  } but the source is not going to bind and the image is not going to display.

Comment: In HTML i give a images [src]="source" and Define the source in component.ts like that    public source="assets/img/{{key}}_inactive.png"; but when i am going to display my page  for images it shows 404 not found error. How can i solve this.

Comment: Which Angular2 version are you using?

Comment: can u tell me how to check angular 2 version? one more thing i am using loop to iterate image  same image is going to repeat on every div.

Comment: check your `package.json` and in there check `dependencies object` and in there check `@angular/core`

Comment: "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",

Comment: canu tell me how to isolate child div from parent div angular2? because i am using loop to iterate image and when i am going to hover an image it showing same image on each div

Comment: Oh I see. Please show it on plunker with relevant example.